# Retrieving data from URL fails

Tags: java, url, get

I have been trying different ways to get data from the following link:
http://www.ensembl.org/Danio_rerio/Export/Output/Location?db=core;flank3_display=300;flank5_display=300;output=fasta;r=18:19408965-19409049;strand=feature;coding=yes;cdna=yes;peptide=yes;utr3=yes;exon=yes;intron=yes;genomic=unmasked;utr5=yes;_format=Text

Copy paste the link to a web browser works for me but I cannot get to it programmatically in java.

It seems that it doesn't follow the get protocol as the separation of parameters is not as expected.
I tried to use URL but it separates the link above into server path and query and results in HTTP 500.
I tried to use sockets but again failed.

I believe that what I need is a way to simply send the complete string unaltered and then read the result.

Any ideas?

Comment: The "it doesn't follow the get protocol" part was funny. Now if you show us the code maybe we can help.

Comment: Please post the Java code that you are using.

Comment: One possibility is the server expecting an HTTP header (v.g. UserAgent), anyway that would be a very twisted situation if that causes a 500.

Comment: @SJuan76 am I missing something? Isn't using ampersand common practice while this one is using semicolon?

Comment: If you put the URL in the browser and get a result then the server follows the "get protocol" (because that is just what the browser uses to retrieve the data that you can see). The semicolon is odd but just ends meaning that the programmer will have to handle the string by itself instead of having the server parse it (again, strange but not impossible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code reads first line from that URL successfully:

```
    URL u = new URL("http://www.ensembl.org/Danio_rerio/Export/Output/Location?db=core;flank3_display=300;flank5_display=300;output=fasta;r=18:19408965-19409049;strand=feature;coding=yes;cdna=yes;peptide=yes;utr3=yes;exon=yes;intron=yes;genomic=unmasked;utr5=yes;_format=Text");
    DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
    String s = ds.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
```

It prints out: `>18 dna:chromosome chromosome:Zv9:18:19408665:19409349:1`

Comment: Thank you, this really showed me that there must have been a problem in my code. 
I was able to fix afterwards; guess I just needed the proof that it works to overcome the problem.